# ZYBO Z7 ADC XAdcPs_GetAdcData send just initial data

Tags: digital-logic, adc, fpga, embedded, arm

Even though I'm resetting the variable **my_raw_data** , the program continues to return the initial data instead of the current data. I use a potentiometer on aux14 port but ı can't take anything but initial data.

Here is my setup:
[image]

Even I change the POT position the following data comes up:
[image]

The code is given. Could anyone help about that?

```
int main(void) {
    int Status;
    XAdcPs_Config *ConfigPtr;
    u32 my_raw_data;
    float my_data;
    XAdcPs *XAdcInstPtr = &XAdcInst;

    ConfigPtr = XAdcPs_LookupConfig(XADC_DEVICE_ID);
    if (ConfigPtr == NULL) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }
    XAdcPs_CfgInitialize(XAdcInstPtr, ConfigPtr, ConfigPtr->BaseAddress);

    // Self Test the XADC/ADC device
    Status = XAdcPs_SelfTest(XAdcInstPtr);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    // Disable the Channel Sequencer before configuring the Sequence registers.
    XAdcPs_SetSequencerMode(XAdcInstPtr, XADCPS_SEQ_MODE_SAFE);

    // Run the polled example, specify the Device ID that is generated in xparameters.h.
    while (1) {
        my_raw_data = XAdcPs_GetAdcData(XAdcInstPtr, XADCPS_CH_AUX_MIN + 14);
        my_data = XAdcPs_RawToVoltage(my_raw_data);
        printf("\r\nThe My data is %0d.%03d Volts. \r\n",
               (int)(my_data), XAdcFractionToInt(my_data));

        my_raw_data = 0;
        printf("Exiting the XAdc Polled Example. \r\n");

        sleep(2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```